# send email based on cell conditional format color change

Tags: excel, vba

i have an working code whereby it sends an email when due to date is coming up however i am now trying to archive something else using the same code however it will only sends out an email when cell color changed to "Yellow" with blank cell and when there is data in the cell with the "Yellow" color it will not send out an email out.

can someone kindly help me please, below it is the partly code whereby it looks for

```
If nameCell.Offset(0, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 And _
        nameCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "" And _
        nameCell.Offset(0, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
    
        ' Store names and expiring dates into array
        Dim infoArray() As Variant
        Dim counter As Long
        ReDim Preserve infoArray(counter)
        
        infoArray(counter) = Array(nameCell.Value, nameCell.Offset(0, 4).Value)
        counter = counter + 1
        
        ' Stamp action log
        nameCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Sent"
        nameCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Environ$("username")
        nameCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "E-mail sent on: " & Now()
        
        ' To be able to check later
        anyExpiring = True
        
    End If

Next nameCell
```

Comment: You do not tell us **which is the conditional formatted cell you are talking about**... Is it `nameCell.Offset(0, 4)`? Anyhow, you used it twice when setting condition... If so, please replace `nameCell.Offset(0, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 6` with `nameCell.Offset(0, 4).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 6`. Otherwise, it does not return the conditional formatted interior color. It returns the cell initial format...

Comment: oh sorry it is on column E

Comment: Your comment is as unclear as the question itself... Are there any explicit "E" in your code? Is the 'nameCell` in column A:A? If yes, my above supposition is correct. Do you understand the code you posted? How do you intend to use `infoArray`? Please, try explaining **in words** what you try doing. But do it in terms used by the code...

Comment: @FaneDuru your suggestion worked. Thank you so much. how do i mark as resolve. Thank you so much

Comment: I will pot an answer, then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use this adapted (part of your code):

```
'your existing code
    If nameCell.Offset(0, 4).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 And _
                                  nameCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "" Then
    
        ' Store names and expiring dates into array
        Dim infoArray() As Variant
        Dim counter As Long
        ReDim Preserve infoArray(counter)
        
        infoArray(counter) = Array(nameCell.Value, nameCell.Offset(0, 4).Value)
        counter = counter + 1
        
        ' Stamp action log
        nameCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Sent"
        nameCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Environ$("username")
        nameCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "E-mail sent on: " & Now()
        
        ' To be able to check later
        anyExpiring = True
        
    End If
```

`DisplayFormat` allows reading the format after Conditional Formatting. Otherwise, `range.Interior.ColorIndex` returns the initial color, without taking in consideration the changes brought by Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Hi Fane sorry how do i also pick up color Pink as well as the yellow

Comment: No problem, when you have quick 5min. I would like to send email when cells has changed either Yellow or Pink or both together. thanks

Comment: @Harin Now I am at home... So, pink color has a lot of nuances. I can show you tenth... So, it is not important to be pink. It must be that pink the validation returns. So, look in the Validation definition and see what is there. If not, let VBA to extract it for you. Activate such a pink cell and run: `Debug.Print ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex`. If it will not return anything, try `Debug.Print ActiveCell.Interior.Color`. Then you use what you can see in Immediate Window (being in VBE: Ctrl + G).

Comment: it is .DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 7, however on same column i have yellow and Pink and when i run the code i want to be able to pick up either yellow or Pink together. i am having issue whereby it will only works with one either Yellow or Pink not together. basically cell will change to yellow if the due date is for this week and change to pink for next week

Comment: Hi Fane https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CxgUa1jvUVKYNMLxes_IZDj5TsKAT5s1/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109388577467569858398&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: i am having now a different issue whereby date which are have formulas on column E it wont copy the same date which is on main sheet call tracker instead it changes the formulas and i have changed it to 14 days due to instead of colors

Comment: If I cannot download the file to see its code and how cell validation has been done, the pseudo shared document is useless. Or maybe I only don't know how to download it... Then, I do not understand anything about formulas, days number instead of colors. I do not know what you are talking about...

Comment: Hi Fane sorry try now: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CxgUa1jvUVKYNMLxes_IZDj5TsKAT5s1/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109388577467569858398&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @Harin I still cannot download/open it on my computer. I think it's time to place another answer, using the code you have now and explaining in details what do you need. If you will tag me and I will be available, I will help with pleasure. If not, somebody else will solve your problem...

Comment: Hi Fane i do not know how to tag you but i placed a new question as below; https://stackoverflow.com/q/68768472/12978314

Comment: @Harin You just did it. Only due to the fact you comment below my answer. Otherwise, you should do as I have just did: Put "@" in front of my user name (FaneDuru).  I cannot make the concatenation here because it will not be allowed, I would receive a message saying that only a user can be notified...