# error with the auto email and excel formulas will not work

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have an sheet whereby i would like to send out an email when the due date is due in 14 days ahead. i have expiry date in column E which is formulated from column D formulas it is =cells in D+K14(59days) and gives you the expiry date in column E.

i would to send email when due date is met copying all of the information from column A-E copied into emails which has the expiry due date however it will need to loop first if the email has already being sent, currently below it is the code whereby i get an error at "  `h = h & "<td>" & rng.Cells(r, c) & "</td>"` "

below it is the code and picture of the sheet

```
Option Explicit

Sub workbook_open()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsBody As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, dtDue As Date, iDays As Long
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iMailRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim sDates As String, dtTimestamp As Date, sStatus As String
    Dim lines As New Collection


    ' delete existing MailBody Sheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
         If ws.Name = "MailBody" Then
            ' Application.DisplayAlerts = False
             ws.Delete
            ' Application.DisplayAlerts = True
         End If
    Next

    ' create new MailBody Sheet
    Set wsBody = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    wsBody.Name = "MailBody"

    ' header row
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Tracker")
    With wsBody.Range("A1:E1")
        .Value2 = ws.Range("A4:E4").Value2
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    iMailRow = 1

    
     iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To iLastRow ' assume row2 is header
        If IsDate(ws.Cells(i, "E")) Then
            dtDue = ws.Cells(i, "E")
            iDays = DateDiff("d", Date, dtDue)
            sStatus = ws.Cells(i, "F")
            dtTimestamp = ws.Cells(i, "H")
            'ws.Cells(i, "X") = iDays
    
            If iDays <= 90 And sStatus <> "Sent" Then
                iMailRow = iMailRow + 1
                ws.Range("A" & i & ":E" & i).Copy wsBody.Range("A" & iMailRow)
                lines.Add i, CStr(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    ' check if any records in collection
    If lines.Count > 0 Then
        ' convert to html
        sDates = Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy") & " and " & Format(Date + 14, "dd mmm yyyy")
        Call SendEmail(wsBody.UsedRange, sDates)
       
        ' record email sent
        For i = 1 To lines.Count
            ws.Range("F" & lines(i)) = "Sent"
            ws.Range("H" & lines(i)) = Now()
        Next
         
    Else
        MsgBox "No records are due", vbInformation, "ID's Due"
    End If
    
    
Sheets("Tracker").Activate
Sheets("Tracker").Range("C2").Select
'Sheet2.Protect Password:="Bhaji2020"

    ' delete temp
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsBody.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub SendEmail(MailBody As Range, sDates As String)

   Const CSS = "<style>p{font:13px Verdana};</style>"
   
   Dim msg As String, outApp, outMail
    Dim msg1 As String
   msg = "<p>Hi" & "<br><br>" & _
"<Font color=red>THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL</font>" & _
   "<br><br>" & "The following applicants ID's are due to expire between <Font color=red> " & sDates & " </font>"

msg1 = "<p>Please arrange individual's new ID's<br><br>Thank you!<br><br>" & _
 Environ("username")

    'Create mail
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
   
    With outMail
  
        .To = "JoeBloggs@yahoo.co.uk"
        .cc = "sSendCC"
        .Subject = "ID's are due in next 14 days"
        .HTMLBody = CSS & msg & RangetoHTML(MailBody) & msg1
        .display
        'send
    End With
    'outApp.Quit
    'Set outApp = Nothing

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range) As String
    
    Dim h As String, c As Integer, r As Long
    h = "<table cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""5"" border=""1"" style=""font:13px Verdana"">"

    For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        h = h & "<tr>"
        For c = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            If r = 1 Then ' header
               h = h & "<th bgcolor=""e0e0e0"">" & rng.Cells(1, c) & "</th>"
            Else
               h = h & "<td>" & rng.Cells(r, c) & "</td>"
            End If
        Next
        h = h & "</tr>"
    Next
    RangetoHTML = h & "</table>"

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: When stopped on error (`h = h & "<td>" & rng.Cells(r, c) & "</td>"`), please move the cursor over `r`, `c` and `rng.Cells(r, c)`. What can you see? Is there a cell value? Are `r` and `c` numbers greater than zero? Is `rng` not nothing? I (just) suppose that `r` may be zero.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru just resolved it. instead of adding two different cells for formulas which was K14 which had days in i just used the simple formulas by the cells in column D+59days and it worked the formulas + no error on the email now however it still sending out an email which falls well over 14days. i would only want the email to be send if the Due date is only 14 days

Comment: Put your excel window and the VB macro window side by side on your screen.  Then run your code line by line by clicking F8 in your starting macro while checking what your code does in excel window.  Move the cursor over your variables and check the values, before & after the relevant commands where you think you failed to check the 14 days condition.

Comment: Hi all Thank you found an silly mistake whereby i had set to 90days instead of 14 days at the code "If iDays <= 90 And sStatus <> "Sent" Then" however now i have faced another problem it is sending all the old date too i can set to only send if the due date falls within 14 days from today date

Answer (score 0):

below line has worked and solved my issue.

```
If iDays > 0 And iDays < 14 And sStatus <> "Sent" Then
```